# How to adjust legend position of interaction.plot and lineplot.CI?

Tags: r, plot, graph, statistics, interaction

I'm a beginner in coding. I was trying to create an interaction plot. Here's my code:

data is clinicaltrials from the [data](https://learningstatisticswithr.com/data.zip) of the book "[Learning Statistics with R.](https://learningstatisticswithr.com/)"

```
library(sciplot)
library(lsr)
library(gplots)
```

```
lineplot.CI(x.factor = clin.trial$drug,
             response = clin.trial$mood.gain,
             group = clin.trial$therapy,
             ci.fun = ciMean,
             xlab = "Drug",
             ylab = "Mood Gain")
```

and it produces the graph like this: 
[image: Interaction Plot 1]

As can be seen in the graph, the legend box is not within my screen.

Also I tried creating another plot using the following code:

```
interaction.plot(x.factor = clin.trial$drug,
                 trace.factor = clin.trial$therapy,
                 response = clin.trial$mood.gain,
                 fun = mean,
                 type = "l",
                 lty = 1,  # line type
                 lwd = 2,  # line width
                 legend = T,
                 xlab = "Drug", ylab = "Mood Gain",
                 col = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
                 xpd = F,
                 trace.label = "Therapy")
```

For this code, I got the graph like this: [image: Interaction plot 2]

In this graph, the legend does not have labels.

Could anyone help me with these problems regarding legend?

Comment: Did you forget to include data and libraries so that anybody could reproduce your issue?

Comment: I added the library and data sets. Thank you for reminding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably plan to save the plot via RStudio GUI. When you resize the plot window with your mouse, you need to run the code again to refresh the legend dimensions.

However, it's advantageous to use a more sophisticated method, e.g. to save it as a `png` with fixed dimensions like so:

```
library("sciplot")
library("lsr")
library("gplots")

png("Plot_1.png", height=400, width=500)
lineplot.CI(x.factor=clin.trial$drug,
            response=clin.trial$mood.gain,
            group=clin.trial$therapy,
            ci.fun=ciMean,
            xlab="Drug",
            ylab="Mood Gain"
)
dev.off()

png("Plot_2.png", height=400, width=500)
interaction.plot(x.factor=clin.trial$drug,
                 trace.factor=clin.trial$therapy,
                 response=clin.trial$mood.gain,
                 fun=mean,
                 type="l",
                 lty=1,  # line type
                 lwd=2,  # line width
                 legend=T,
                 xlab="Drug", ylab="Mood Gain",
                 col=c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"),
                 xpd=F,
                 trace.label="Therapy")
dev.off()
```

[image]

[image]

The plots are saved into your working directory, check `getwd()` .

### Edit

You could also adjust the legend position.

In `lineplot.CI` you may use arguments; either by using characters just for `x`, e.g. `x.leg="topleft"` or both coordinates as numeric `x.leg=.8, y.leg=2.2`.

`interaction.plot` does not provide yet this functionality. I provide a hacked version below. Arguments are called `xleg` and `yleg`, functionality as above.

See `?legend` for further explanations.

```
interaction.plot <- function (x.factor, trace.factor, response, fun = mean,
                              type = c("l", "p", "b", "o", "c"), legend = TRUE, 
                              trace.label = deparse(substitute(trace.factor)), 
                              fixed = FALSE, xlab = deparse(substitute(x.factor)),
                              ylab = ylabel, ylim = range(cells, na.rm = TRUE), 
                              lty = nc:1, col = 1, pch = c(1L:9, 0, letters), 
                              xpd = NULL, leg.bg = par("bg"), leg.bty = "n", 
                              xtick = FALSE, xaxt = par("xaxt"), axes = TRUE, 
                              xleg=NULL, yleg=NULL, ...) {
  ylabel <- paste(deparse(substitute(fun)), "of ", deparse(substitute(response)))
  type <- match.arg(type)
  cells <- tapply(response, list(x.factor, trace.factor), fun)
  nr <- nrow(cells)
  nc <- ncol(cells)
  xvals <- 1L:nr
  if (is.ordered(x.factor)) {
    wn <- getOption("warn")
    options(warn = -1)
    xnm <- as.numeric(levels(x.factor))
    options(warn = wn)
    if (!anyNA(xnm)) 
      xvals <- xnm
  }
  xlabs <- rownames(cells)
  ylabs <- colnames(cells)
  nch <- max(sapply(ylabs, nchar, type = "width"))
  if (is.null(xlabs)) 
    xlabs <- as.character(xvals)
  if (is.null(ylabs)) 
    ylabs <- as.character(1L:nc)
  xlim <- range(xvals)
  if (is.null(xleg)) {
    xleg <- xlim[2L] + 0.05 * diff(xlim)
    xlim <- xlim + c(-0.2/nr, if (legend) 0.2 + 0.02 * nch else 0.2/nr) * 
      diff(xlim)
  }
  dev.hold()
  on.exit(dev.flush())
  matplot(xvals, cells, ..., type = type, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, 
          xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, axes = axes, xaxt = "n", 
          col = col, lty = lty, pch = pch)
  if (axes && xaxt != "n") {
    axisInt <- function(x, main, sub, lwd, bg, log, asp, 
                        ...) axis(1, x, ...)
    mgp. <- par("mgp")
    if (!xtick) 
      mgp.[2L] <- 0
    axisInt(1, at = xvals, labels = xlabs, tick = xtick, 
            mgp = mgp., xaxt = xaxt, ...)
  }
  if (legend) {
    yrng <- diff(ylim)
    if (is.null(yleg))
      yleg <- ylim[2L] - 0.1 * yrng
    if (!is.null(xpd) || {
      xpd. <- par("xpd")
      !is.na(xpd.) && !xpd. && (xpd <- TRUE)
    }) {
      op <- par(xpd = xpd)
      on.exit(par(op), add = TRUE)
    }
    # text(xleg, ylim[2L] - 0.05 * yrng, paste("  ", 
    #                                          trace.label), adj = 0)
    if (!fixed) {
      ord <- sort.list(cells[nr, ], decreasing = TRUE)
      ylabs <- ylabs[ord]
      lty <- lty[1 + (ord - 1)%%length(lty)]
      col <- col[1 + (ord - 1)%%length(col)]
      pch <- pch[ord]
    }
    legend(xleg, yleg, legend = ylabs, col = col, 
           title = if (trace.label == "") NULL else trace.label,
           pch = if (type %in% c("p", "b")) 
             pch, lty = if (type %in% c("l", "b")) 
               lty, bty = leg.bty, bg = leg.bg)
  }
  invisible()
}
```

---

*Data:*

```
lk <- "https://learningstatisticswithr.com/data.zip"
tmp <- tempfile()
tmp.dir <- tempdir()
download.file(lk, tmp)
unzip(tmp, exdir=tmp.dir)
load("data/clinicaltrial.Rdata")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However, I was wondering if there's other way that I can just display the plots without saving it?

Comment: To be more specific, is there a argument/function that helps position the legend or expand the dimension?